# flexible date parsing

Tags: vb.net, parsing, date

I have a lot of different date format that one of my field can contain.  And I'm trying to parse it but it some times doesn't understand the format at all and returns 1900-01-01.
Or sometimes, it invert months, days and year: 2023-12-11 instead of 2012-11-23.

The field is contained in a total of 1500-2500 excel files, that are produced by some kind of scanner.  Dates and time are in different cases.

I've seen different formats such as these so far: 
yyyy-mm-dd or mm/dd/yy and some others (that i cant find because i dont want to spend the day oppenning random excel files hoping to find a different format ^^')

So... I've tried parsing it at hand (Substring of the different fields), but it still has bugs, so:

**Is there any date parsing tool for VB that works often?**

I imagine there is a library or something that can parse dates from almost any format already coded, and if I could avoid to recode it I'd be quite happy :)

Comment: Why are you asking for _efficient_? I would ask for anything that _works_ for all of your _unknown_ formats instead.

Comment: `DateTime.ParseExact` allows you to specify the exact formatting of the input string.  You'll still need to be able to determine the correct format string to give it, though.

Comment: I'm not asking for something that works _every time_ ... I meant _efficient_ as works _often_.

Answer (score 4):

No, of course there is nothing that can parse dates in any (unknown) format. How should it know what to do with `9/10/11`? That can be anything.

So you can use [`TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9h21f14e.aspx) or [`TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/h9b85w22.aspx) (you can even pass a `string[]` for multiple allowed formats) and pass the correct `CultureInfo`.

Comment: I'm already using those. What I ask for isn't something that **always** works, just something that **works often**... And if this doesn't exist yet, it SHOULD! because there is a lot of conventions for dates, usually the date formats stays within a certain order. As for 10/10/10, it usually is month day, year no? 
and 2012-01-01 is yyyy-mm-dd not yyyy-dd-mm, 
it's just conventions, a library as I ask for would just try every formats from the more plausible to the less while parsing...

Comment: @LudovicMigneault An individual date like 01/10/10 is ambiguous, and can cause bad data. The convention is for you is not the same for someone from another country. However, while using cautious assumptions, if you can retain the source of the scans & determine with reasonable certainty that date formats are the same within the group, for a large enough group of scans, you may be able to determine the format based on other dates in the same field like 19/10/15 or 10/19/15.
. . .   
It's really not a unique problem! I agree it should and probably does exist - if you find it let me know.

Comment: I posted the question 3 years ago, on my 1st internship ^^'
 I don't do VB anymore, but date parsing always bring the same problem it seems. 
To answer my question, I'd simply say "NO, there isn't shuch a pluggin". Because nothing "official" would leave a big margin of error like we get when parsing dates without enough informations.
My reccomendation would be to either convert the date to a timestamp (no parsing error can come from parsing an int) OR use your own format for CREATING and READING the date ;  this way you know what to expect.